# Capitalize the first string in list using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list containing strings and I want capitalize the first letter of first string using Python and not the entire list.

I have attempted the following but every first letter in the list is capitalized:

```
L = ("hello", "what", "is", "your", "name")

LCaps = [str.capitalize(element) for element in L)
print LCaps
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to capitalize the first string and only the first string of a tuple.  Use:

```
>>> L = ("hello", "what", "is", "your", "name")
>>> (L[0].capitalize(),) + L[1:]
('Hello', 'what', 'is', 'your', 'name')
```

Key points:

1. Strings have methods.  There is no need to use the string module: just use the strings `capitalize` method.
2. By running `L[0].capitalize()`, we capitalize the first string but none of the others.
3. Because `L` is a tuple, we can't change the first string in-place.  We can however capitalize the first string and concatenate it with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (L[0].title(),) + L[1:]
```

You can use title() too.